# Toggle FN lock via applescript in macos Ventura (13.1)

Tags: keyboard, applescript

Cutting code from various sources and came up with this monster, but I'm unable to get it to select the function keys panel. The checkbox works if I manually select it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
do shell script "open -b com.apple.systempreferences " & ¬
"/System/Library/PreferencePanes/Keyboard.prefPane"

tell application "System Events"
tell its application process "System Settings"
    click button 1 of group 2 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 2 ¬
        of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window "Keyboard"
    delay 0.1
    click UI element 1 of row 11 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard"
    delay 0.1
    repeat until checkbox "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" of group 1 of scroll area 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard" exists
    end repeat
    click checkbox "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" of group 1 of scroll area 1 of group 2 ¬
        of splitter group 1 of group 1 of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard"
end tell 
end tell
```

Specifically it is this line that is not working:

```
    click UI element 1 of row 11 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard"
```

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer to it in case anyone needs it in the future.

This boss solved it here by using keyboard navigation!

https://github.com/MrSimonC/Toggle-Mac-Function-Keys

Comment: unfortunally doesn't work for macos 13.3, apple has moved this setting in other place, again

Comment: hm, I'm on Ventura 13.3 and it still works great for me